# Android - Closing specific Bluetooth socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, connection

I'm trying to use an Android device to connect to Bluetooth devices to retrieve some information. In particular I'm trying to connect to Bluetooth headphones on this UUID:

```
"0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
```

To do this I'm creating a socket and connecting it to the remote device this way:

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
    // because mmSocket is final.
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    try {
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice.
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used in the server code.
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_HF);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed", e);
    }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception.

        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
        }
        return;
    }

    // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
    // the connection in a separate thread.
    manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);}
```

It works fine when the headphones are not yet connected with my Android device. But what happens is that the headphones connect automatically with my Android device thanks to the OS itself. And in this case, when I execute the mmSocket.connect() method, it does not return. I thought that maybe Android has connected automatically another socket with the same UUID and so mine doesn't work. Do you think this is the problem? And if it is, is there a way to close all the sockets between my Android device and a remote Bluetooth device? Or maybe just the one that is bothering my process?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what actually happens is the OS is doing the paired device criteria to save some battery as  the searching process consume a lot of energy. 
since you've done the search you should go for searching in paired devices not normal search and the result of the search should be taken from
Query paired devices

Before performing device discovery, it's worth querying the set of paired devices to see if the desired device is already known. To do so, call getBondedDevices(). This returns a set of BluetoothDevice objects representing paired devices. For example, you can query all paired devices and get the name and MAC address of each device, as the following code snippet demonstrates:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
// There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    String deviceName = device.getName();
    String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
    }
}
```

To initiate a connection with a Bluetooth device, all that's needed from the associated BluetoothDevice object is the MAC address, which you retrieve by calling getAddress(). You can learn more about creating a connection in the section about Connecting Devices.

this is the official documentation from google  covering every detail about Bluetooth:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I've already followed the procedure for the connection as showed by Google. The problem is that when I try to create a connection to retrieve some data from the remote device and my Android device is already connected via Bluetooth (connection made automatically by Android) to that remote device, my attempt to connect won't be successful and the connect() method won't return.